# SQLite database not working when called

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, navigation-drawer

I use an SQLite database for a project about different noodles. For the project I use a navigation drawer and calls the data from the database. Somehow when I try to query data an `SQLiteException` is thrown and nothing happens.

Why doesn't it work?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_noodle);
        //set up toolbar as the normal app bar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        ListView noodleListPerCategory = findViewById(R.id.selected_noodleList);

        try {
            database = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            fetch();

            //create the cursor adapter to fill the list view with values from the database
            SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, new String[]{"NAME"},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
            noodleListPerCategory.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Database is  not working!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

        //show item detail using the listener when an item is clicked
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> noodleListPerCategory, View view, int position, long id) {
                //starts DetailActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(NoodleActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.CHOSEN_NOODLE_ITEM, (int) id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        //connects the listener to the list view
        noodleListPerCategory.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
         public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
            cursor.close();
            database.close();
        }

    public Cursor fetch() {
        cursor = this.database.query("NOODLE", new String[]{"_id", "NAME"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: In `catch`, add  `e.printStackTrace();` then edit your question to include the stacktrace as code. However, before running **a)** change `SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);` to **`DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);`** and **b)** delete the App's data (or uninstall the App, which deletes the App's data), then try running again.

Answer (score 0):

Having created a test based upon both this question and your previous question. The issue is mainly in your database helper class `DatabaseHelper`;

In the **`addNoodle`** method you close the database, this results in the database being closed as per :-

```
11-07 12:59:35.188 2986-2986/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: mjt.noodle, PID: 2986
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mjt.noodle/mjt.noodle.Noodle}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/mjt.noodle/databases/NoodleDB
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/mjt.noodle/databases/NoodleDB
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:520)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:262)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                     at mjt.noodle.Noodle.onCreate(Noodle.java:35)
```

***Note! line numbers will not match as I made amendments to simplify testing.*** (i.e. the log is shown to give you some idea of the issue)

**Removing** the **`db.close();`** in the **`addNoodle`** and then either **deleting the App's data** or (uninstalling the App) will fix this issue.

Rightfully you should also replace

`SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);` with
**`Databasehelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);`**

As you really want a DatabaseHelper object rather than an SQLiteOpenHelper object. However, this doesn't at this stage cause an issue, but could later be confusing or cause issues.

For testing this I used the following :-

#### Noodle.java :-

```
public class Noodle extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Cursor cursor;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_noodle);
        //set up toolbar as the normal app bar
        //Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        ListView noodleListPerCategory = findViewById(R.id.selected_noodleList);

        try {
            database = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            fetch();

            //create the cursor adapter to fill the list view with values from the database
            SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, new String[]{"NAME"},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
            noodleListPerCategory.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Database is  not working!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

        //show item detail using the listener when an item is clicked
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> noodleListPerCategory, View view, int position, long id) {
                //starts DetailActivity
                /*
                Intent intent = new Intent(NoodleActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.CHOSEN_NOODLE_ITEM, (int) id);
                startActivity(intent);
                */
            }
        };
        //connects the listener to the list view
        noodleListPerCategory.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        cursor.close();
        database.close();
    }

    public Cursor fetch() {
        cursor = this.database.query("NOODLE", new String[]{"_id", "NAME"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

along with

#### DatabaseHelper.java :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //the name for the database
    private static final String DATABASENAME = "NoodleDB";
    //the initial version of the database
    private static final int DATABASEVERSION = 1;
    private Noodle noodle;
    //SQLiteDatabase db;

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASENAME, null, DATABASEVERSION);
        //db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        updateDatabase(db, 0, DATABASEVERSION);

    }

    /**
     * this method updates the database if the db helper's version number is higher than the version number on the db.
     *
     * @param db             The SQLite database
     * @param currentVersion The user's version number of the database
     * @param updatedVersion The new version of the database written in the helper's code
     */

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int currentVersion, int updatedVersion) {
        updateDatabase(db, currentVersion, updatedVersion);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when you want to set the database back to its previous version
     *
     * @param db             The SQLite database
     * @param currentVersion The user's version number of the database
     * @param updatedVersion The new version of the database written in the helper's code
     */
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int currentVersion, int updatedVersion) {

    }

    /**
     * This method is for adding new noodle dish to the database
     */
    private void addNoodle(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String description, int imageid, String restaurant) {
        ContentValues noodleValues = new ContentValues();
        noodleValues.put("NAME", name);
        noodleValues.put("DESCRIPTION", description);
        noodleValues.put("IMAGEID", imageid);
        noodleValues.put("RESTAURANT", restaurant);
        db.insert("NOODLE", null, noodleValues);
        //db.close();

    }

    private void updateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, int currentVersion, int updatedVersion) {
        if(currentVersion >= 1 || currentVersion < 1 ) {
            //execute SQL on the db and create a new NOODLE table
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE NOODLE ("
                    + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "NAME TEXT, "
                    + "DESCRIPTION TEXT, "
                    + "IMAGEID INTEGER, "
                    + "RESTAURANT TEXT, "
                    + "FAVORITE NUMERIC, "
                    + "CATEGORY TEXT);");
            addNoodle(db,"Spicy Ramen", "Chicken broth, marinated pork, chilli and bean sprouts", 1, "Totemo");
            addNoodle(db,"Tokyo Ramen", "Dashi-based broth, marinated pork and fermented bamboo shoots", 2, "Totemo");
            addNoodle(db,"Vegetarian Ramen", "Mushroom dashi-based broth, tofu, pak choi, miso and corn", 3, "Ramen Manga");
            addNoodle(db,"Miso Ramen", "Miso broth, marinated pork, egg, spring onion and bean sprouts", 4, "Cafe Steigman");
            addNoodle(db,"Tonkatsu Ramen", "Pork bone based broth, grilled pork, spicy garlic with miso", 5, "Blue Light Yokohama");
            addNoodle(db,"Shio Ramen", "Seasalt broth, pork, egg, quail and vegetable", 6, "Ai Ramen");
            addNoodle(db,"Nabeyaki Udon", "Udon noodles in fish broth with chicken, shrimp, egg and leek", 7, "Ki-mama Ramen");
        }
        if(currentVersion <=2) {

        }
    }
}
```

and, although pretty irrelevant

#### activity_noodle.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mjt.noodle.Noodle">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/selected_noodleList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The above resulting in :-

[image]

Comment: I did a test project using these exact same code that you use for testing and the list of noodles is not showing  up :( I wonder what is wrong....

Comment: Did you delete the App's data before running?

Comment: 1st thing to do is split the problem up, say by determining if the issue is with the listview or before with data extracttion so immediately after the fetch you could add `Log.d("NOODLE", "Extracted " + Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()) + " rows from Database.");`, delete the App's data and then rerun and then check the log to see what the message says. You would expect to get something like **11-08 07:04:23.944 2509-2509/? D/NOODLE: Extracted 7 rows from Database.** If you do then the issue is with displaying the ListView, if you get 0 then the issue is extracting the data from the cursor.